# Having count, group by but keep other datas

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, having

I am trying to retrieve data about products in mysql table, table is pivot table contains caracteristics id.

My goal is filter into data matching multiple criterias selected by customer.

My request works to filter products id but i want to keep all other datas (values) about products, i do not know if it's possible in one single request, i want to avoid another request with the result of the first one.

Example for products 72252 keep values 1,2,3,4,17,18,19,20,9,21,11,22,23,24,25 etc ...

SQL fiddle example with request (2 values selected)

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49b59d/3)

Thanks by advance,

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure you know what you want. You should give a simple example with the table data, and the expected output.

Comment: You are right, Perhaps not enough clear, i want all values of products contains values selected by customer. If 1and 2 selected then retrieve all values for products contains 1 and 2. More clear ?

Comment: It will be more clear if you modify your answer with explicit examples. It doesn't have to be all your data, but words are difficult to understand. A table is easy.

Comment: Hi, found a solution to get data i need, but not the best for performance i think, updated SQL fiddle : [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49b59d/4, someone has better request ?